# Size of structure - padding and alignment

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have an explicitly sized structure as follow:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long                   A : 4;
    unsigned long                   B : 12;
    union
    {
        unsigned long               C1 : 8;
        unsigned long               C2 : 8;
        unsigned long               C3 : 8;
    };
    unsigned long                   D : 8;
}FooStruct;
```

The total size of this struct should be 32bit (4 bytes) in theory. However, I get a 12-byte size using `sizeof` so there should be some padding and alignment happening here.

I just don't see why and where. Can someone explain to me how this structure takes 12 bytes in memory?

Comment: `typedef struct` is that `c` or `c++`? In `c++` we don't need the typedef.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the total number of bits used explicitly without any padding. But If every field gets padding to reach 4bytes it will be 16 bytes. I just don't understand how it ends up being 12bytes.

Comment: @drescherjm, doesn't change a thing. I tested both signatures. Just copied this one here.

Comment: bit field is implementation defined also, I suppose that your compiler doesn't share union and non union data.

Comment: @Jarod42, The thing is, that I either have 4 fields here or 6 fields. In any case, 12 is a very unusual size for any of those. This seems like the first two fields get merged into 2 bytes and padded by two, union taking another 2bytes and they padded by 2 as well as the last field. But for some reason, the last field does not get merged with the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union forces the start of a new unsigned long, and the member after the union yet another unsigned long. Assuming long is 4 bytes that means your struct will have 3 unsigned longs for a total of 12 bytes. Although a union with three equally sized members also seems odd.

If you want this to have a size of 4 bytes why not change it to:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short                   A : 4;
    unsigned short                   B : 12;

    union
    {
        unsigned char               C1 : 8;
        unsigned char               C2 : 8;
        unsigned char               C3 : 8;
    };

    unsigned char                   D : 8;
}FooStruct;
```

Comment: This makes sense, So the first two fields take 4 bytes shared, the union takes 4 bytes by itself and the last field takes another 4 bytes?

Comment: *"The union forces"* Not sure, it is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally if you are using gcc and want to disable structure padding, you can use `__attribute__((packed))`:

```
struct FooStruct
{
    unsigned long                   A : 4;
    unsigned long                   B : 12;
    union
    {
        unsigned long               C1 : 8;
        unsigned long               C2 : 8;
        unsigned long               C3 : 8;
    } __attribute__((packed)) C;
    unsigned long                   D : 8;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

But beware that some architectures may have penalities on unalligned data access or not allow it at all.